# SQL - Transpose/Pivot Rows to Column

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

I have a data extension with values like:

```
Email_Address | Job_ID  | Date    | Etc
wmcm@me.com   | 1234    | 1/11/19 | etc
wmcm@me.com   | 5678    | 1/11/19 | etc
wmcm@me.com   | 9432    | 1/11/19 | etc
```

Using SQL, I want to pivot this flatten into a single row and have all Jobs as a string in 1 field :

```
Email_Address   |  All_Jobs 
wmcm@me.com     | 1234, 5678, 9432
```

My approaches so far of using the SQL Pivot function fails as an unsupported MC Function.

Any ideas how this could be done ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try doing a XML Path on a subquery and wrap it in a STUFF to create your delimited string.

Basically what this will do is pull in each value via the subquery and xml path and then STUFF will turn it into a comma delimited string (or whatever delimiter you want).

It surprisingly is efficient and quick so it can slide into your query without heavily increasing run time / processing pull as some other solutions can be.

Sample:

```
SELECT  a.PrimaryKey
        , DelimitedString =
        STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + b.MultipleValueField
               FROM (
                        SELECT   sub.PrimaryKey
                               , sub.MultipleValueField
                        FROM [yourSourceDE] sub
                    ) b
               WHERE b.PrimaryKey = a.PrimaryKey
         FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
FROM [yourSourceDE] a
```

I added in DISTINCT to only display unique values. If you want ALL values - including duplicates, you can remove the DISTINCT and it should pull in every value.